# How to interchange words in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

This is my input line
`[[ref:start|Other config files, programs, and scripts]]`

and I need to convert above line into
 `"Other config files, programs, and scripts":ref/start`

How can I convert this using the sed command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to write than to read :)

```
$ echo "[[ref:start|Other config files, programs, and scripts]]" |\
  sed 's/\[\[\([^:]*\):\([^|]*\)|\(.*\)\]\]/"\3":\1\/\2/'
"Other config files, programs, and scripts":ref/start
```

I'd recommend you read [`man sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) as well as [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). It's not that big and you actually don't need to read it all at once. In most cases it's sufficient to know `s///` command, regular expression syntax and sed's flags (most useful are `-n` and `-i`).

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain why we need the portion [^:]* and [^|]*?

Comment: `[^:]` matches one character which is not colon (or newline) and `*` matches zero or more of them, always as many as possible. Thus `[^:]*` matches up to just before the colon delimiter. Similarly `[^|]*` matches up to just before the pipe delimiter.

Comment: If there could be several of these expressions on the same input line, you should guard against matching past a closing square bracket, too, and add a `/g` option; `sed 's%\[\[\([^]:]*\):\([^]|]*\)|\([^]]*\)\]\]%"\3":\1/\2%g'`